# For which p is the Markov chain recurrent (almost random walk)

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

> We have a Markov chain on Z with matrix:
>   $p_{ii+1}=p=1-p_{ii-1}$ for $i\leqslant-1$,   $p_{ii-1}=p=1-p_{ii+1}$ for $i\geqslant1$, and $p_{00}=p_{01}=p_{-10}=\frac{1}{3}$.
>    For which values of p is this chain recurrent?

**My attempts/intuition:**
I suppose that if $p\geqslant \frac{1}{2}$ then the chain is recurrent but I dont know how to prove it. Maybe it could be helpful to consider $|X_n|$?
I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: So in short, the chain moves toward $0$ (if it isn't there already) with probability $p$ and away with probability $1-p$, and if the current state is $0$, the next state is equally likely to be $-1, 0,$ or $1$?  I would definitely consider $|X_n|$, and then show that the state $0$ is recurrent or transient, as appropriate.

Comment: Yes, but how to prove it?